# Client Server JRE usage

Tags: java

I have developed a server application running in Wildfly and a client connecting on this server. What would happen if my client would use Java 1.7 (32bit) and my application server Java 1.6 (64bit)?

Comment: Nothing, internet communication has nothing to do with the java version

Comment: But what about deserialized objects?

Comment: It should not be a problem. Serialized objects shouldn't depend on the version with which you compiled the class

Comment: The things really matter are the data and the network protocols used.

Comment: And there should be no incompatibility of the used java classes (respectively their implementations and standards)? Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization in Java is independent of the architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit). All data types use the same number of bits, regardless. The only difference is the Reference data type, which is 32-bit or 64-bit respectively, but this "data" is never serialized (it is a pointer to the memory address), instead, the data it references is serialized.